# Display only some Hyperref rectangles

Tags: hyperref

I'm writing the following documents. As you can see it's shown only on one page, so in order not to make it a colorful painting I have switched off the colored rectangle around the many links displayed in the final PDF.

[image: Example]

I want to display a colored rectangle only on some of these links. How can I do this? Based on my knowledge the option is an on/off one to be set in the preamble.

Here a MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{} %\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Logo}}
\lfoot{\href{www.facebook.com}{www.facebook.com/mypage}}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\href{mailto: mymail@fmail.it}{mymail@fmail.it}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ----------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=200pt]{Image} \\[10pt]
\Huge \textbf{My Name} \\[5pt]
\Large My home town \\ My Birthday \\
\end{center}

\textbf{BIOGRAFY} \\

\lipsum[3]

\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{}

\vfill

Text with one hyperlink \href{www.facebook.com}    {www.facebook.com/mypage}  \\[10pt]

\textbf{Link with a colored rectangle} - \href{http://goo.gl}{www.goo.gl} \\
\textbf{Link with a colored rectangle} - \href{http://goo.gl}{www.goo.gl} \\[10pt]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Have you tried `\hypersetup{}` with your options in between (should be something that removes the hidelinks and then after the box sets it again)?

Comment: Do you mean setting off at the beginning and then set the option on locally with the command `\hypersetup{}` in the two lines where I want the rectangle to show on.

Comment: Yeah, I mean something like `\hypersetup{colorlinks}\url{link}\hypersetup{hidelinks}` (of course this makes color, but should be similar for boxes).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a version with borders locally enabled:

[image: links and rectangle]

```
\documentclass[11pt, a4]{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{}
\chead{}
\rhead{} %\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{Logo}}
\lfoot{\href{www.facebook.com}{www.facebook.com/mypage}}
\cfoot{}
\rfoot{\href{mailto: mymail@fmail.it}{mymail@fmail.it}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0.0pt}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\usepackage{lipsum}

% ----------------------------------------------------

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{fancy}

\begin{center}
\includegraphics[width=200pt]{Image} \\[10pt]
\Huge \textbf{My Name} \\[5pt]
\Large My home town \\ My Birthday \\
\end{center}

\textbf{BIOGRAFY} \\

\lipsum[3]

\parbox{0.5\textwidth}{}

\vfill

Text with one hyperlink \href{www.facebook.com}    {www.facebook.com/mypage}  \\[10pt]

\hypersetup{pdfborder=1 1 1}
\textbf{Link with a colored rectangle} - \href{http://goo.gl}{www.goo.gl} \\
\textbf{Link with a colored rectangle} - \href{http://goo.gl}{www.goo.gl} \\[10pt]
\hypersetup{hidelinks}

\href{http://goo.gl}{Test}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use a group around the `\hypersetup` macros, you don't have to revert manually then.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Would be an option, but I don't think I need to add it as you stated it in the comments.

Comment: @TeXnician: That's why I wrote 'you could', not 'you should' ;-)